# Get "Undefined" for snapshot values

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

[log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l48Sw.png)

[inside of the log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdgTq.png)
I am currently in the process of setting up my Firebase Cloud functions to have a user to user push notification everytime there is a new child added to "Messages". For each user, there is a notification stored in a node in this structure "/User/UID/Token". However, in my logs in the Firebase console it turns up that values being returned is "Undefined". This is my first time working with Node.js so everything is very new. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what is inside of function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.messageWritten =     functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

console.log('Push notification event triggered');

//  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime   Database.
var valueObject = event.data.val();
console.log(valueObject.text,valueObject.toId);

return admin.database().ref(`/Users/${valueObject.toId}`).once('value').then(snapshot =>{
    console.log('the users name',snapshot.name)
    console.log('the users token',snapshot.token)
})


// Create a notification
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title:snapshot.name +' sent you a message', 
        body: valueObject.text,
        sound: "default"
    },
};

 //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the  notification and the priority
const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};


  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.token, payload, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `return` statements in your function. The code after the first return statement (which sends the message) won't be run.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.messageWritten = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime   Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();
    console.log(valueObject.text, valueObject.toId);

    return admin.database().ref(`/Users/${valueObject.toId}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        console.log('the users name', snapshot.val().name)
        console.log('the users token', snapshot.val().token)

        // Create a notification
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: snapshot.val().name + ' sent you a message',
                body: valueObject.text,
                sound: "default"
            },
        };

        //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the  notification and the priority
        const options = {
            priority: "high",
            timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val().token, payload, options);
    })
});
```

Comment: I just tried the code you suggested but it still is coming up as undefined, I provided screenshots of what is happening in the question

Comment: Yeah, `snapshot.token` won't work. You probably want `snapshot.val().token`. I highly recommend reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) before continuing. A few hours spent there, will save you much time and many stack overflow questions down the line.